# Sending string one component to other component in angular2

Tags: angular

I want to send username from my login component to home component ...how can i do this please tell me with simple example which showing sending string from one component to another i use angular2 CLI and vs code editor

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0):

Use **@Input**

import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector:'counter',
    Inputs: ['number']
})
export class CounterComponent {

```
@Input()
count: number = 0;
```

}

@Component({
    selector: 'counter-sibling',
    template: ''
})
export class CounterSibling{

```
@Output()
count: number = 0;
```

}
usage in counter-sibling:

Comment: Thank you siddhi , sorry but i didn't understand what happening in ur code  .. please give me simple example of Two different components passing single string to other one .

Comment: in counter component we are taking input from counter-sibling.